# Strong spin-orbit coupling allowing for fast qubit manipulation in Ge based heterostructures

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-spin, spin-orbit

I have been reading about [Ge/SiGe hole qubit resaerch](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-1919-3.pdf) and noticed that the strong intrinsic spin orbit coupling (SOC) replaces on-chip micromagnet often found on [Si/SiGe based spin qubits](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1603251113).

The reason for on-chip micromagnet for Si/SiGe spin qubits is the lack of SOC, requiring one to generate artificial SOC for spin manipulation.

I have an intuitive picture for the Si/SiGe qubits; as you electrically jiggle the electron trapped in quantum dots, the magnetic field gradient physically moves the spin of the electron.

However, I don't have such an intuitive picture for the Ge/SiGe case, which uses the material's intrinsic SOC.  I believe it is the angular momentum of the hole spin experiences in $ \hat{\mathcal{H}} = S \cdot L   $.  In the Si/SiGe case where you have a micro magnet on your chip, by sending AC electric field, you can move the electron back and forth.  In the Ge/SiGe case, would the equivalent picture be sending an AC electric field, jiggling the hole wave function in and out of different angular momentum values?